# Unsure where to delete object

Tags: c++, delete-operator

I have the following class which stores pairs of dates and prices:

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include "boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp"

using std::vector;
using std::pair;
using boost::gregorian::date;

class A {
private:
    vector<pair<date*, float> > prices;
public:
    A(pair<date*, float> p[], int length) : prices(p, p + length) { }
};
```

An object of this class is created and filled with data with the following function:

```
A loadData() {
    // create price array
    pair<date*, float> *prices = new pair<date*, float>[10];

    // fill array with data (normally read from a file)
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        prices[i].first = new date(2012, 4, 19);
        prices[i].second = 100;
    }

    // create the object using the price array
    A result(prices, 10);

    // delete the price array (its contents have been moved to result's vector)
    delete[] prices;

    return result;
}
```

Given this setup, where would I call delete to free the memory allocated when creating each date object in the loadData function? My first guess was to delete the dates in A's deconstructor, but what if the dates passed to the constructor are to be used elsewhere outside of class A?

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why would they  be passed to somewhere else? There's no code that does that. And why do you have to separate variables named the same? That's a recipe for disaster!

Comment: Is there a geniune need to use pointers to dates here?  Dont use pointers and heap allocation unless you really have to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless you have very good reason to do so, forget about the pointers:

```
A loadData() {
    // create price array
    vector<pair<date, float> > prices;

    // fill array with data (normally read from a file)
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        prices.push_back(make_pair(date(2012, 4, 19), 100));
    }

    // create and return the object using the price array
    return result(prices);

}
```

and modify the class accordingly:

```
class A {
private:
    vector<pair<date, float> > prices;
public:
    explicit A(const std::vector<pair<date, float> >& p) : prices(p) { }
};
```

Then you don't have to worry about memory management. The compiler will make optimizations such that the code above performs less copies than you would imagine.

Comment: This is a small part of a much larger assignment, so the restriction to using date pointers is one I have to follow, even if it's somewhat artificial.

However, I will keep this idea in mind when working on my own projects. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidThielke who is supposed to ultimately own the pointers? The answer would really depend on that.

Comment: I suppose class A owns the pointers, so it's okay for its destructor to handle their cleanup. Framing the question like that helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a shared_ptr (from boost or tr1) for automatic memory clean up:

```
vector<pair<boost::shared_ptr<date>, float> > prices;
```

I would also suggest to make `prices` in loadData a std::vector, instead of an array.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for keeping pointers in a container would be using `boost::shared_ptr`/`std::shared_ptr`. Then they will destroy contained objects when, their reference count drops to 0, and you don't have to worry about where it happens.

Comment: I think this is a pretty bad solution, you're just tip-toeing around the fact that you have to make up your mind about the ownership of objects. You just give up, throw your hands in the air and say "Oh well, everybody owns it!".